# codeigniter auto loading the database even though i removed from autoload.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a site in php and I am using `codeigniter` as framework.

I removed database in `$autoload['libraries']` from `autoload.php`. But it is showing error when i removed database credentials from `database.php`.

I don't understand the problem here.I must be able to load the site without a database connection. According to the documentation I just shouldn't load any database. But it is throwing an error. How to resolve this issue?

The error is:

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

```
Filename: C:\wamp\www\mlp\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Line Number: 124

Comment: what is the error? you mind posting it here

Answer (score 3):

You may be calling database library by loading it somewhere in your script. by using `$this->library->load('database')` try removing that. ... ELSE ...Try to clear your browser cache... Refresh the project once... Restart apache(if it doesnt work even after the previous two).

Answer (score 0):

If you removed database from autoload.php it is not possible to show the error message, if this message is showing you had used the library any of your controller.